# html form issue sending with php

Tags: php, html, forms

I copied this PHP and HTML from the web, and added a couple more variables… I can't seem to get it to work (The site is hosted on JustHost - Linux).

I've Googled and read all that I found, and tried all of it. Nothing seems to work for me. I figured I must just be over looking something simple??

I know there's a lot out there regarding this, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

The php.ini has:

SMTP = localhost

smtp_port = 25

Below is the Error, PHP, and HTML Form.

**Error:**

"We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. These errors appear below.

We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.

Please go back and fix these errors."

**PHP:**

```
        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



            // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

            $email_to = "jeff@selectionsllc.com";

            $email_subject = "I'm Interested In This Line!";





            function died($error) {

                // your error code can go here

                echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

                echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

                echo $error."<br /><br />";

                echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

                die();

            }



            // validation expected data exists

            if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

                !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

                !isset($_POST['store_name']) ||

                !isset($_POST['email']) ||

                !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

                !isset($_POST['line']) ||

                !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

                died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');

            }



            $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

            $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

            $store_name = $_POST['store_name']; // required

            $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

            $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

            $line = $_POST['line']; // not required

            $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



            $error_message = "";

            $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

        if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

            $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

        }

            $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

            $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

        }

        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

            $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

        }

        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$store_name)) {

            $error_message .= 'The Store Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

        }

        if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

            $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

        }

        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

            died($error_message);

        }

            $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



            function clean_string($string) {

            $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

            return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

            }



            $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

            $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

            $email_message .= "Store Name: ".clean_string($store_name)."\n";

            $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

            $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

            $email_message .= "Line: ".clean_string($line)."\n";

            $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





        // create email headers

        $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

        ?>



        Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



        <?php

        }

        ?>
```

**HTML Form:**

```
  <form method="post" action="send_form_email.php" name="Inquiry" target="_new">
    <table width="450px">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><label for="first_name">First Name *</label></td>
        <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><label for="last_name">Last Name *</label></td>
        <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><label for="store_name">Store Name *</label></td>
        <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="store_name" maxlength="50" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><label for="email">Email Address *</label></td>
        <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="tel" name="telephone" pattern="^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$" required size="30" placeholder="555-555-5555"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><label for="line">Line Name</label></td>
        <td valign="top"><input  type="text" name="line" value="JStar Jewelry Designs" maxlength="30" size="30" disabled></td>
      </tr>
        <td valign="top"><label for="comments">Comments *</label></td>
        <td valign="top"><textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: please don't validate email addresses like that, or names

Comment: I don't think Jeff will be too happy when he googles his site and finds the source code posted here

Comment: @andrew it looks like it is from http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php and I think this is the 5th question I have seen this week with this exact code and issue.

Comment: Yes, the form is from freecontactform.com/email_form.php… I must have deleted that from the code when I was messing with the submit button.

Comment: Dagon, thanks for pointing that out. I will look into a better way/right way to validate email addresses, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your fields are considered as required ( on the php file, you are validating that any POST variable you are receiving is set ) but it looks like you are not considering the inputs "telephone" and "line" as mandatory in the html code. Have you tried what happens if you fill all the inputs in the form?

In case "line" and "telephone" are optional, you should change these lines on your php:

```
        if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

            !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

            !isset($_POST['store_name']) ||

            !isset($_POST['email']) ||

            !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

            !isset($_POST['line']) ||

            !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');

        }
```

for this:

```
        if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

            !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

            !isset($_POST['store_name']) ||

            !isset($_POST['email']) ||

            !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');

        }
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thank you!! I do recall looking at that and thinking it wasn't right… but I'm a noob.